# How can I SQL Join 2 databases with only distinct results in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am using an interactive SQL tutorial (you can grab the structure from http://sol.gfxile.net/) to help me solve a real-world issue. I'm having problems getting distinct results in my left table, while still returning non-null results in my right SQL table. Here are my tries and results:

```
SELECT stars.name as sn, planets.name 
FROM stars LEFT OUTER JOIN planets 
ON stars.starid=planets.starid

sn      name
O-00000 (null)
G-00001 (null)
M-00002 (null)
K-00003 (null)
G-00004 (null)
G-00005 G-00005/A
G-00005 G-00005/B
```

In try 1, I got results in the 'names' column, but dupes in my 'sn' column bc some stars have multiple planets. Try 2:

```
SELECT stars.name, planets.name 
FROM stars LEFT OUTER JOIN planets 
ON stars.starid=planets.starid
where not exists (
    select 1 from stars
    where stars.starid = planets.starid
)

name    name
O-00000 (null)
G-00001 (null)
M-00002 (null)
K-00003 (null)
G-00004 (null)
```

In try 2, I got unique records in column1, but all nulls in column 2.. How can I get both uniques in column1, and non-nulls in column2?

Comment: But you had it in 1 query already? what is wrong with first result? could you present expected result you need?

Comment: In case of G-00005 you have two planets. How to define which one of them you want to see in your expected result?

Comment: -Alex The first result duplicates G-00005 in the left col. @Guneli, I don't mind what condition is used to show a planet result, only that 1 planet per star is shown, if there even is a planet. I'm aware that some stars will show null in the planet column, but col2 should show max 1 planet per star

Comment: @dharkko so you want random replacement of starname to any pllnet name belongs to that star  G-00005/A or G-00005/B? any of that would be good for you?

Comment: Then do a GROUP BY, and MIN/MAX/WHATEVER...

Comment: @Alex , yes. I'm trying to randomly replace any planet that belongs to a star with just 1 planet instance per star.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your goal but try:

```
SELECT COALSCE(planets.name,stars.name) as name  
FROM stars LEFT JOIN planets 
ON stars.starid=planets.starid
GROUP BY stars.starid
```

or maybe you want

```
SELECT stars.name as sn, planets.name  
FROM stars LEFT JOIN planets 
ON stars.starid=planets.starid
GROUP BY stars.starid
```

Comment: Specifically, this answer works best for me bc it maintains column headers as compared to other options.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thank you. Good luck with your project!\

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every star has unique name, you can try this:

```
SELECT s.name as sn, (SELECT MAX(name) FROM planets WHERE starid=s.starid) 
FROM stars s;
```

OR

```
SELECT s.name as sn, (SELECT name FROM planets WHERE starid=s.starid LIMIT 1) 
FROM stars s;
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work nicely - I guess I thought I would need to use a join - thx